# I don't understand how to interpret ++a * ++a

Tags: c, pre-increment

Can anybody tell me how the answer of this code is 16 25

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define sqr(x) ++x * ++x
int main()
{
  int a = 3, z;
  z = ++a * ++a;     
  a -= 3;
  printf("%d %d", sqr(a), z);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the code with `-Wall` option gives the following warning:

> [Warning] operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]

The results are platform and version dependent. Using such an expression results undefined behaviour. Therefore, such an expression must not be used.

Comment: So if two or more pre/post increment or decrement operators are multiplied (or divided or added or subtracted),then we should first evaluate increment or decrement operator then perform multiplication or division?

Comment: Not only it's not recommended, it's **plain wrong** to do this. 1: it's undefined behaviour, 2: the code is hard to understand.

Comment: Actually it's not mine code.This code was a MCQ asked in the exam.